# Getting polyline midpoint coordinates using ArcGIS REST API

Tags: line, arcgis-rest-api, parameters, centroids, request

I have an ArcGIS 10.7.1 feature service that integrates polyline GIS assets to a work order management system.

In the work order management system, I want to retrieve the midpoint coordinates of the currently selected polyline asset.

[image]

I think the best way to do this would be to request the midpoint coordinates of the specific polyline feature from the feature service/REST API.

---

*Note: There are ways to do this with the REST API for the centroid/centerpoint of **polygons**. But they don't seem to apply to the **midpoint of polylines**.*

> [ArcGIS REST API - Query (Feature Service/Layer)](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm)
>
> `returnCentroid (Optional)`
>
> The returnCentroid parameter is currently **only supported for polygon
>   data.**

---

Is it possible to get the coordinates of a polyline's midpoint using the REST API?

Comment: A code attempt for doing this for polylines could be the code you use to do it or something similar for polygons.

Comment: The midpoint of a line is a basic bit of JavaScript if the client doesn't support it directly. This doesn't really seem like a server-side task.

Comment: @Vince To clarify, are you suggesting that I could calculate the midpoint of a line by doing math on the vertices?

Comment: If the API doesn't support it, sure.

Comment: You've presented some code documentation rather than a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers).

Comment: All you need to start is to calculate a Cartesian distance, then walk the segments a second time to pro-rate the location along the middle segment. It might not matter to compute a geodesic length and to prorate a geodesic midpoint, though this could certainly be accomplished with a Server Object Extension (SOE) using ArcObjects Java (albeit with two more magnitudes of effort)